# Mapbox GL Geolocate, not showing an indicator of where I am

Tags: mapbox-gl

Been browsing a web recently and I am wondering if it is possible to see my location as a dot indicator if I am using `Mapbox GL`?

I am using latest `Mapbox GL` feature called `Geolocate`

I am creating a control like this

```
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Geolocate({position: 'bottom-right'}));
```

This adds an arrow indicator that I can press and it will jump to my location. But I cannot see a dot, or a circle that would indicate my current location.

As I understand it is a new feature in `Mapbox GL` and there is no much support out there. But I was wondering if someone else has encountered that.

Answer (score 1):

The Mapbox team purposely did not implement a dot / marker in order to give developers more flexibility. Instead, you can listen to the geolocate event to handle this and add a marker as you see fit.

See this thread here for the discussion: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2824

Copying from the thread, the right way to handle the geolocation event is:

```
var geolocate = new mapboxgl.Geolocate();
map.addControl(geolocate);

geolocate.on('geolocate', function(e) {
  // console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right. geolocate event getting fired every 6 seconds.